# Laravel whereHas Returns all records

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have have 3 tables in my projects they are:

- products(can have Multiple Variants)
- variants (belongsto product)
- product_attributes (this have product_id,attribute_id,value_id)

I want to filter variants from a product by value ids thats comes from form request as example (1,2,6)

I have tried like this:

```
$poruduct_id = $request->product_id;
    
$value_ids = $request->value_ids;
    
$searched_variants = Variant::whereHas('product.attributeValues', function ($query) use ($value_ids, $product_id) {
    $query->whereIn('value_id', [$value_ids]);
})->where('product_id', $product_id)->get();

dd($searched_variants);
```

But the problem is the query returns all records from the product. What is the solution to filter exactly the values that the product Variants have?

Thank you.

-**UPDATED**-

I have tried like this but nothing changed

```
$searched_variants = Variant::select('product_id')->whereHas('product.attributeValues', function ($query) use ($value_ids, $product_id) {
    $query->whereIn('value_id', [$value_ids]);
})->groupBy('product_id')
    ->havingRaw('COUNT(*) = ?', [count((array) $value_ids)])
    ->get();

-**FİNALLY SOLUTİON**-

I made it like this : I get the value code that is in for example Large the code is L 

get all the codes to controller and executed this query ı hope this helps someone 

 1.$value_codes=$request->value_codes;

 2.$value_codes_array=explode(',',$value_codes);

 3.$product_id=$request->product_id;

 4.$searchValues = preg_split('/,/', $value_codes_array, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);


    $searchValues = preg_split('/,/', $value_idss, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

        $variants= Variant::where(function ($q) use ($searchValues) {
            foreach ($searchValues as $value) {
                $q->orWhere('sku', 'like', "%-{$value}")
                    ->orWhere('sku', 'like', "%-{$value}-%")
                    ->orWhere('sku', 'like', "{$value}-%");
            }
        })->where('product_id',$product_id)->get();
      
dd($variants);
```

Answer (score 0):

If  you have n variants to one product, you query should be like:

Product Model

public function variants: HasMany relationships

//usage
$produtc->variants->and here the query function

Comment: hi thank u for response my relation is like u said but ı want filter the variants by product->attributeValues have u an idea ?

Comment: you could use a query function instead get to investigate the final query result to know in what parts of that query is the problem, if you can't find the problem in the query update the aswer and put here to every one see

Answer (score 0):

You need to use it in this way, it should work:

```
$productId = $request->product_id;

$valueIds = $request->value_ids;

$searchedVariants = Variant::whereHas('product.attributeValues', function ($query) use ($valueIds) {
    $query->distinct()->whereIn('value_id', $valueIds);
}, '=', count($valueIds))->where('product_id', $productId)->get();
```

Comment: ı used exactly the same query what u send but now the query returns empty records and ı am sure there are variants with the search result